# Cant conect to MS SQL using a JSF project with maven

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, mssql-jdbc

I've been trying with Microsoft official JDBC drivers from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
Tried with the latest and oldest, even other random ones, and still no success.

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager
```

I also tried other suggestions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64386147/13924032
Deleted the sun folder and still the same error.

This is the dependency I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Also my connection code is this:

```
    public void ConectarSQL() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if(con != null) {
               DatabaseMetaData metaObj = (DatabaseMetaData) con.getMetaData();
               System.out.println("Driver Name?= " + metaObj.getDriverName() + ", Driver Version?= " + metaObj.getDriverVersion() + ", Product Name?= " + metaObj.getDatabaseProductName() + ", Product Version?= " + metaObj.getDatabaseProductVersion());
            }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The DataBaseMetaData is just for testing the connection.

Am I missing something? this is my first time working with maven, haven't had any issue with simple java projects.

I'm using glassfish server 5
Java EE 8 Web
JSF 2.3
JDK 1.8 (1.8.0_131)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone going through this same issue. I managed to get it running by downloading and setting a fresh glassfish server (v5.1.0), also installing JDK 1.8_281, and explicitly setting up the glassfish server to run with JDK 1.8_281.
After this, I didn't get the error anymore.
And for some reason the latest driver didn't work with this configuration for some reason, I don't know why, but 7.4.1jre8 did the job.